# Slow compiling of large documents in TeXstudio

Tags: compiling

I am new to the TeX community. I have a question that has been troubling me for the last year or more, that I am hoping to find help with. I have been using LaTeX for 2 or 3 years now. I am on the crux of completing my Master's thesis which I have written in LaTeX.

**My question** is about the lengthy compilation time that LaTeX (in combination with TeXstudio) is taking to render my document. My thesis has grown to around 150 pages, with about 50 pages of figures and tables that were generated in R. On its first compilation it can take well over 10 minutes. The compilation time does decrease after the first compilation but is still very lengthy. I have read other posts and seen suggestions about compiling multifile documents with the `\include` macro.

What can I look into to speed up the compilation of my thesis in LaTeX/TeXstudio? Is it the large number of graphics that are included? Or, perhaps their file size?

I am using the `\graphicspath{}` command below in the preamble to insert files in figures and appendix with `\includegraphics{}`.

```
\graphicspath{{Graphics/}{C:/Users/Desktop/Grad/Thesis/Data/Analysis/PlotOutputs/}}
```

I am also using `natbib` for my bibliography with about 80 entrys. The code for this is as expected.

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{C:/Users/Desktop/Grad/Thesis/Masters_Bibliography}
```

When my compilations are successful without some other error I have created the log pane shows this:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=batchmode "Masters_Thesis".tex

Process exited normally

Process started: bibtex.exe "Masters_Thesis"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: texstudio_PT5388.aux
The style file: apalike.bst
Database file #1: C:/Users/Jesse/Desktop/Grad/Latex/Documents/Thesis/FinalThesis/Masters_Thesis.bib

Process exited normally

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=batchmode "Masters_Thesis".tex
```

**Lastly**, any MWE always runs very quickly so I don't think that would be helpful.

Any suggestions on things I might look into with my inserted graphics or BibTeX usage or otherwise would be overly appreciated. I have missed more than one deadline because of these issues.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` or `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, which could speed up compilation - but don't forget to remove the option when you are ready to submit your thesis :)